# How to give right path in .bat file to copy file from windows server to local windows

Tags: batch-file, cmd, xcopy

Hi I am making a batch file that will copy a file from the users c drive of a server to the local machine.

This is what i have so far.

```
net use "\\\Trail01" "trail@1234" "/USER:ashique.sheikh"

XCOPY /Y "\\\Trail01\c:\Users\ashique.sheikh\Desktop\Day2.R"  "D:\newfolder"
```

My server name is `\\Trail01`.

The file path is `c:\Users\ashique.sheikh\Desktop\Day2.R`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you will need the admin credentials for the net use though as the C drive is an administrative share

```
net use N: \\trail01\c$ trail@1234 /USER:ashique.sheikh

XCOPY /Y "N:\Users\ashique.sheikh\Desktop\Day2.R" "D:\newfolder"
```

Comment: It gives error System error 67 has occurred.

The network name cannot be found.

Comment: run the 2 commands seperately in a cmd window, which part fails? I'm guessing it cannot see the server properly, ensure you can UNC to the path first

Comment: It gives error in first command                                                       System error 67 has occurred.

The network name cannot be found.

Comment: it cannot see the server properly, check you can UNC to the path and check it is visible on the network, once it is visible on the network then it will be able to complete successfully, please mark the above as the answer if this works for you.

Comment: I have the access to folder when i take control remotely i can see my drives and access the file there.